# Components in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a component which uses a static and a dynamic class, i.e. one of the classes is only added when certain conditions apply.

Currnetly I use the following constructs and it works, but it is probably not the most "stylish" way to do it... How would you do it?

I am especially worried about the way I layed out the html and the "class" attribute in particular..

tile.component.html

```html
<div class="tile {{level}}">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

tile.component.scss

```css
.tile {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: var(--ion-item-background,var(--ion-background-color,#fff));

  --border-color: grey;
  --border-style: solid;
  --border-width: 0px 0px 0.55px 0px;
  --inner-border-width: 0px 0px 0.55px 0px;

  border-width: var(--inner-border-width);
  border-style: var(--border-style);
  border-color: var(--border-color);

  &.alert {
    border-color: #a80000;
    border-width: 0 0 6px 0;
  }

  &.warn {
    border-color: #dba020;
    border-width: 0 0 6px 0;
  }
}
```

tile.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Host } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tile',
  templateUrl: './tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile.component.scss']
})
export class TileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() warnlevel: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get level() {
    return this.warnlevel;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything is fine, just some cleanup and you can also use **[ngClass]** directive, it will append class evaluated by dynamic expression. Also you can use **union type** to reduce possible values of **warn level**.

---

tile.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tile',
  templateUrl: './tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile.component.scss']
})
export class TileComponent {
  @Input() warnlevel: "notification" | "warning" | "error";
}
```

tile.component.html:

```
<div class="tile" [ngClass]="warnlevel">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error:

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Did you import **CommonModule** from "@angular/common" in your module?